# controlar estado de inputs en formulario con el onChange en la etiqueta <form>

Tags: reactjs

quiero controlar el estado de un formulario en React desde la etiqueta  sin que de error, ya controlo el formulario pero me dice dando el error de que le ponga onChange en el input

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que tienes hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Da mas detalles y un ejemplo de como lo estás trabajando. Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @padaleiana <form onChange={xfunction}> esto controla el formulario y los inputs pero me da error en consola